# js: using replace method to strip string of all non-alpha numeric with exceptions?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am creating a storage path and using `replace(/[^a-z0-9]/gi, '')` to remove all non-alpha numeric characters from a string but now I want to allow `-` and `_` , since those are valid in paths.  How can I modify my `replace` method to have it remove all non-alpha numeric characters with the exception of `-` and `_` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your regex says to "replace every char EXCEPT these ones", add them to your regex, as so:

```js
replace(/[^a-z0-9-_]/gi, '')
//               ^
```

Both hyphen and underscore characters don't need any escape sequences. However, in order to stop the regex from ever confusing the hyphen for a range of characters, you can also add a \ to escape the hyphen:

```js
replace(/[^a-z0-9\-_]/gi, '')
//               ^ extra backslash
```